# chrome extension to write user data on an existing excel sheet

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension with user form, which has list of existing bookmark folder in chrome and user comment via text box.

Is it possible to write the user form data to an existing excel sheet in local drive, with aid of chrome extension ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

chrome extension is not alowed to access local files([see here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/aj4X_sA44JI)).

to solve this problem, I sugest you to building a little webapp, host it on you localhost or server, then use XMLHttpRequest send your user data to your webapp, after that you can write it on an existing excel sheet.

Comment: here is how to use XMLHttpRequest  in content scripts on any other file of google extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!, I'll try the method you've suggested and get back on this.

Comment: @ HankYang: It seems i've to use NPAPI plugin to trigger external program and pass value from chrome extension. Am i right ?

Comment: Is it possible to write an external file, if popup uses HTML5 methods to write a file ?

Comment: as I kown, you can not write local file in chrome extension,even via popup. so I think you should try to write a tiny web APP in PHP,there is much more class with write excel file function.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I'm entriely new to extension development, i'll study PHP for my requirement and will get back on this.
Thanks

Comment: from my understanding php needs a hosting server with php installation to execute php code. is there anyother method. I found this is product forum:http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/a6VndWVvbQY which says they don't support php long back.. I don't know current status.

Comment: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side 
 and 

http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/


Can we use this HTML5 api to save a notepad of extension extracted data to local file system. Or is it blocked in Chrome extension ?